# Automate Google Chrome using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate Chrome browser using VBA-Selenium basic.

I started writing below code:

```
Sub callChrome()
    Dim chromeObj As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    'Set chromeObj = New ChromeDriver
    
    chromeObj.Start "chrome"
    chromeObj.Get "www.google.co.in"
    
End Sub
```

But it gives an error saying:
Selenium Error
invalid argument

[vba chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXSbd.png)

Can anybody please help on this error.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: Get rid of this line `chromeObj.Start "chrome"`. Does error still occur? And does it occur on the .Get line?

Comment: Press debug and find out what line this is on, then edit your question to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private chromeObj As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub callChrome()

    Set chromeObj = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

    chromeObj.Start baseUrl:="https://www.google.co.in"
    chromeObj.Get "/"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.